# xfce4-indicator-plugin

Tags: xfce

System:

- Kernel: 5.8.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0
- Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2
- Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)

`xfce4-indicator-plugin` does not have Sound Menu, purged and reinstalled, no help

Thanks a lot!

[image: with sound menu]

[image: without sound menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to (re)install single Indicator Sound [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/indicator-sound) by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-sound
```

then reboot.